# How to hide the particular row of already existing grid programatically

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, opacity, silverlight-5.0

I had created a grid(**silverlight5**) by doing this `Grid bigGrid = new Grid();` using silverlight.
Then i assign it 3 columns and 7 rows in it.

Now each cell has a textblock. And it works fine.

I have to create opacity on any `particular` row of this already existing grid (bigGrid).And this particular row will be decided dynamically.

**How to achieve this in c# code ?**
I mean i need something like :
bigGrid.row[particularRow].Opacity=true;  (could someone please correct me ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to achieve this.

First, you can't simply set a row(`RowDefinition`)'s `Opacity`, because `RowDefinition` is not a `UIElement`. What you can do is that you set the `Opacity` all the elements on this row to `0`. In your case the elements would be 3 `TextBlocks`.

Also you can create a `Rectangle` on top of the entire row (`RowSpan` of 3) and set its `Fill` color to match your `Grid`'s color as well as its `Opacity` to `0`. When you want to hide this row, simply set the `Rectangle`'s Opacity to 1 to block the visual of the `TextBlocks`.

Comment: Xin thanks for the theortical answer. But silverlight code is bit diferent then .net . How to code for it in silverlight.

Comment: I am talking `Silverlight` here, not `.NET`. You just need to do YourTextBlcok.Opacity = 0. In your case you will need to do this to three `TextBlocks`.

Comment: Ok but your rectangle sounds me more beautiful way.

Comment: In that case you will need to create 7 `Rectangles`, each fills an entire row, is this what you really want?

Comment: yes. But actually my bigGrid contains 7 grids (in each row)(like this Gird smallGrid = new smallGrid Grid(); I didnt explained in question because i wanted to make it less complex) and now i need to create rectangle in each these small 7 grids.

Comment: Oh... Does each smallGrid contain 3 `TextBlocks`? In this case you don't need `Rectangles` at all! Just do `smallGrid.Opacity = "0"`;

Comment: yes, Ok let me try this will mark you soon as it works.